# How to send commands on NON-Player Gameobjects in Unity

Tags: c#, client-server, host, unity-game-engine

I am unable to send commands from my gun prefabs in my game. How can I send commands from non-player game objects? Every time I try to send a command, I get an error. I do not want to move my shooting scripts from my guns to my player, as this method will require me to change my game drastically.

My Shooting Script:

```
[Command]
    void CmdOpenFire(){


    if (Physics.Raycast(camTransform.TransformPoint(startPosition), camTransform.forward, out hit, range)){
        gunsMasterScript.CallEventShotDefault(hit.point, hit.transform);
        if (hit.transform.parent != null) {
            if (hit.transform.parent.CompareTag ("Enemy")) {

                gunsMasterScript.CallEventShotEnemy (hit.point, hit.transform.parent);
            }
        }


        if (hit.transform.tag == "Player") {
            gunsMasterScript.CallEventShotEnemy (hit.point, hit.transform);
        }
    }

}
```

My shooting Detection script:

```
public PlayerManager_AmmoBox localPlayerTester;
public GunsManager_GunsAmmo gunsAmmo;
public GunsManager_GunsMaster gunMaster;
float nextAttack;
public float attackRate = 0.5f; 
Transform myTransform;
public bool isAutomatic = true;
public bool hasBurstFire;
bool isBurstFireActive;
public string attackButtonName;
public string reloadButtonName;
public string burstFireButtonName;
NetworkIdentity netID;

// Use this for initialization
void OnEnable () {
    if (transform.root != null) {
        if (transform.root.GetComponent<PlayerManager_AmmoBox> () != null) {
            localPlayerTester = transform.root.GetComponent<PlayerManager_AmmoBox> ();
        }
    }
    SetInitialReferences ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (localPlayerTester != null) {
        CheckIfWeaponShouldAttack ();
        CheckForReloadRequest ();
        CheckForBurstFireToggle ();
    }

}
void SetInitialReferences(){
    netID = GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ();
    myTransform = transform;
    gunMaster = transform.GetComponent<GunsManager_GunsMaster> ();
    gunsAmmo = transform.GetComponent<GunsManager_GunsAmmo> ();
     gunMaster.isGunLoaded = true; 
}


void CheckIfWeaponShouldAttack(){

    if (gunMaster != null) {
        if (Time.time > nextAttack && Time.timeScale > 0 && myTransform.root.CompareTag ("Player") && gunMaster.isGunLoaded) {


                if (isAutomatic && !isBurstFireActive) {
                if (Input.GetButton (attackButtonName)) {
                    AttemptAttack ();
                }

            } else if (isAutomatic && isBurstFireActive) {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown (attackButtonName)) {
                    StartCoroutine (RunBurstFire ());

                }

            } else if (!isAutomatic) {

                if (Input.GetButton (attackButtonName)) {
                    AttemptAttack ();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

void AttemptAttack(){
    nextAttack = Time.time + attackRate;
    if (gunMaster.isGunLoaded) {

        gunMaster.CallEventPlayerInput ();

    } else {

        gunMaster.CallEventGunNotUsable ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to provide a little more info, I'm having trouble understanding your question and what your goal is.

Comment: @AdamB My question is, "Are there any ways that I can send commands from non-player game objects".